# How to prevent tclIndex collisions?

Tags: tcl

If multiple tcl scripts are running in the same directory, they can crash if one tries to auto_mkindex at the same exact time as another.

How can I prevent this properly?  I do not want to just place catch around auto_mkindex, nor do I want to implement a semaphore system for this simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you be building the `tclIndex` files at the same time in the first place? That's a step that I would expect as part of installation (i.e., something done once as a special action) and not as part of operation (i.e., many times, in parallel potentially). If it's part of installation, it's entirely your own problem if you try to run the code while you're installing it.

I also wouldn't tend to use `tclIndex` for anything shared between applications, as that's optimized for simple scripts. Shared components are better off made into packages, especially as they're versioned entities, and they have their own indexing mechanism (the `pkgIndex.tcl`). (Having the same version of the same package installed twice in such a way that things interfere… well, that wouldn't be sensible, would it?)

Comment: The user can have a local version of a tcl file in the current directory.  As long as . is first in auto_path, then the system will pick the procs from the local file.  This way, one can easily make one-off script modifications for a particular run. I think maybe best is to check the modification time of the tclIndex relative to .tcl files in the dir.